# Calling F# discriminated union from C# method using UWP, .NET Core v2.0.3 and C# v7.3?

Tags: c#, uwp, f#

Our app’s UWP libraries limit us to using .NET Core 2.0.3.  Our code uses C# v7.3 and we have been experimenting with F#.

How does one handle a discriminated union returned from F# in in our versions of .NET Core v2.0.3 and C# v7.3?

Some advice is to [use a C# switch to handle an F# function returned discriminated union](https://connelhooley.uk/blog/2017/04/30/f-sharp-to-c-sharp#cases-with-types%20below).

Putting the following F# and C# code in a test Console app with and F# and C# project...

**F#**

```
type LogLevels =
| Error
| Warning
| Info
```

**C# calling F#**

```
private static void Main()
{
    LogLevels level = LogLevels.Info;
    switch (level.Tag)
    {
        case LogLevels.Tags.Error:
            Console.WriteLine("error");
            break;
        case LogLevels.Tags.Warning:
            Console.WriteLine("warning");
            break;
        case LogLevels.Tags.Info:
            Console.WriteLine("info"); //prints info
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

*….works fine just as @madreflection says.*

But if a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` is returned instead of an `int` I get the compiler error `CS8370: Feature ‘type pattern’ is not available in C# 7.3.  Please use language version 9.0 or greater.`

*In my attempt* I retrieve a key from an Azure key vault using an API that works in C# and should in F#.

The **F# code** is …

```
type public SENSITIVE_ITEM =
| SECRET_C of KeyVaultSecret
| KEY_C of KeyVaultKey

type public TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM =
| TASK_GET_SECRET_C of Task<Azure.Response<KeyVaultSecret>>
| TASK_GET_KEY_C of Task<Azure.Response<KeyVaultKey>>

let GetAsync ( item : SENSITIVE_ITEM) (vaultURI : Uri) : TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM =
    match item with
    | SECRET_C(secret) -> VClient_Secret(vaultURI).GetSecretAsync(secret.Name) |> TASK_GET_SECRET_C
    | KEY_C(key) -> VClient_Key(vaultURI).GetKeyAsync(key.Name) |> TASK_GET_KEY_C
```

...and the **C# code** in my unit test for `GetAsync` is …

```
public void GetAsync_Key()
{
    KeyVaultKey key = new KeyVaultKey(keyName);

    var fs_sensitive_item_key = KeyVaultAccess.SENSITIVE_ITEM.NewKEY_C(key);

    var task = KeyVaultAccess.GetAsync(fs_sensitive_item_key, vaultUri);
    switch (task)
    {
        case KeyVaultAccess.TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM.TASK_GET_KEY_C:
            Console.WriteLine("got a key task.");
            break;
        case KeyVaultAccess.TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM.TASK_GET_SECRET_C:
            Console.WriteLine("got a secret task.");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    Assert.True(false);
}
```

The two C# `case` match expressions give the error.  This is probably because C# 7.0.3 doesn’t support pattern matches in switches. (as the error says).

This is a problem as [UWP is not supported in .NET 5.0](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet/issues/120) which is needed to use C# v9.0 or greater.

So, How does one handle a discriminated union returned from F# in in our limited versions of .NET Core v2.0.3 and C# v7.3?

Comment: Most C# 9.0 features will work on older runtime versions with minor shims required for some of them, e.g. init-only accessors (covariant returns being the one that absolutely must have .NET 5 or higher because change were made to the runtime to support it). "Support" is a little misleading. There's a difference between what's technically supported (Microsoft will provide technical support for it) and what's functionally supported (the runtime will run the code). The latter is broader.

Comment: That said, I tried your code with the runtime and language targets you specified and it worked.

Comment: Suggestion: If your discriminated union is really that simple, you could just make it an enum that C# will understand natively.

Comment: @madreflection  - I updated with my code which I thought might be too messy to show.  Apologies, that was a mistake.  The new code definitely shows the error and hopefully clarifies my question.  Thank you, Richard

Comment: @brianberns - I should have included the full question with all the failing code; sorry.  I've updated and I hope clarified my question; thank you.

Comment: Using the `Tags` nested class members should work, just as you had it before, e.g. `case KeyVaultAccess.TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM.Tags.TASK_GET_KEY_C`

Comment: @madreflection - your answer works.  I wrote it up with my working version of the ```switch``` statement.  If you cut-and-paste it into your own asnwer I will upvote and mark it as the answer.  Thank you.    (PS. eventually if you don't I'll make the answer myself but I want you to get the credit).

Comment: I'm a bit occupied right now. Go ahead and self-answer (don't forget to remove it from the question -- the answer is supposed to be separate). Thanks for the consideration, though.

Comment: Besides, in the process of trying simplify the question (a minimal, reproducible example), you actually solved the problem yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the advice from *madreflection* I figured this out...

Use the `*.Tags.*` nested class members as follows...

```
switch (task.Tag)
    {
    case KeyVaultAccess.TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM.Tags.TASK_GET_KEY_C:
        Console.WriteLine("got a key task.");
        break;
    case KeyVaultAccess.TASK_SENSITIVE_ITEM.Tags.TASK_GET_SECRET_C:
        Console.WriteLine("got a secret task.");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("default.");
        break;
    }
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

The F# compiler generates so called "augmentations" for Discriminated Unions.

When using your `LogLevel` type from C# you can access/check for a certain case using the generated `Is[caseName]` Properties.

https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfALgTwA4FMAEAZA9gOa6YBumwE2AvALABQi2AogE6v6sNMDqAhqwB2AS0GFu2AJKCw+IA

Discriminated Union with case values.

https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AdACoAWATugIYwCWmA5lQxANYQCwAKEFF8GbAHVaDVBlrYAvNkGJsAQWzIw2Sl24AeAEbJkwAHzLsAIQ1adPPcVqs2poA=

Comment: You greatly added to my understanding of what is going on and how to find out for myself the next time; thank you.